# php print preview for form only

Tags: php, print-preview

I am a newbie in php code and I have been create a print button but it show the content of whole page.I want to create a print preview that just print for the content of form. So how I need to do, someone help me please....and here is my code.

**reserve.php**

```
<?php include('header_user.php');?>
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
<div id="contentleft">
<div class="reserve-form">
    <h1>Make Reserve</h1>
<form action="reservation.inc.php" method="POST">
    <!--username-->
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Your username" required="">
    <!--username-->
    </br>
    <!--person-->
    <label for="hperson"><b>Person</b></label>
    <select id="person" name="person">
        <option selected hidden>How many person?</option>
        <option value="1 Person">1 Person</option>
        <option value="2 Person">2 Person</option>
        <option value="3 Person">3 Person</option>
        <option value="4 Person">4 Person</option>
        <option value="5 Person">5 Person</option>
    </select>
    <!--person-->
    </br>
    <!--date-->
    <label for="wdate"><b>Date</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="bookdate" placeholder="dd-MM-yy" required="">
    <!--date-->
    </br>
    <!--time-->
    <label for="wtime"><b>Time</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="booktime" placeholder="0.00pm" required="">
    <!--time-->
    </br>
    <!--Select Table-->
    <label for="rtable"><b>Table No</b></label>
    <select id="table" name="booktable">
        <option selected hidden>Choose your table</option>
        <option value="T1">T1</option>
        <option value="T2">T2</option>
        <option value="T3">T3</option>
        <option value="T4">T4</option>
        <option value="T5">T5</option>
    </select>
    <!--end select-->
    <button type="submit" name="confirm" class="loginbtn">Confirm</button>
    <a class="print_btn" href="" onclick="window.print();">Print</a>
</form> 
</div>
</div><!--contentleft-->
<?php include('sidebar.php');?>
</div><!--content-->
</div><!--container-->
<?php include('footer_user.php');?>
```

Comment: Have the print link pop up a new tab. Supply the page for the information you want printed. search on how to tell the browser to print.

Comment: Can you just create a `print` media CSS style sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with a CSS3 media tag. Give the part you do not want to be shown a html class, like "no-print", then add a media print contidion to your css:

```
@media print {
    .no-print {
        display: none;
    }
}
```